# Why is Visual Studio generating code with errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Whenever I am trying to use the emulator VS auto generates a piece of code which has an error inside it that is blocking the app from working

```
namespace MyApp {


[global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("NotePage.xaml")]
public partial class NotePage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {
    
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage NotePage;
    
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(NotePage));
        NotePage = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage>(this, "NotePage");
    }
}
```

It gives an error under the first NotePage with the error code CS0542, saying "NotePage: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type".

This is the main XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:mmvm="clr-namespace:MvvmHelpers;assembly=MvvmHelpers"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
         x:Class="MyApp.NotePage"
         BackgroundColor="White"
         x:Name="NotePage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:NoteViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ListView
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneTime}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Note}"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    RefreshControlColor="DarkViolet"
    SelectionMode="None"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">
    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:NoteViewModel">
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <MenuItem
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference NotePage}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            IsDestructive="True"
                            Text="Delete" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label
                             FontSize="Large"
                             Text="{Binding Title}"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label
                             FontSize="Large"
                             Text="{Binding Content}"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And I can't place initialize component under this, because it says it doesnt exist in the current context:

```
public partial class NotePage : ContentPage
    {
        public NotePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it helps a great deal if you post the error message, not just the code.  I doubt many of us have the C# error codes memorized.   You should also post the XAML that is generating this code.  There is likely a problem in the XAML that is causing the generated C# to have an error.

Comment: @Jason I deleted the generated c# and now its only giving me an error on the initialize component part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
x:Name="NotePage"
```

and

```
x:Class="MyApp.NotePage"
```

this is a problem because it is trying to create a member variable named `NotePage` but the name of the class is also `NotePage`.  This is exactly what CS0542 is telling you, "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am struggling on finding which one is the variable? I have an almost identical xaml cluster (as in `public partial class HomePage : ContentPage` , `public HomePage()
        { InitializeComponent();}`, and `x:Class="MyApp.HomePage"`

Comment: `x:Name` is creating a member variable.  Rename it to something that does not conflict with the class name

Comment: Hello, its unrelated to the question but it is in the same code and I found an answer made by you to another post similar to an issue to mine. When I use `x:DataType="viewmodel:NoteViewModel"` I get member not found in data context "NoteViewModel" for the Binding Context, but when I delete `x:DataType="viewmodel:NoteViewModel"` the binding Context fixes but it breaks all the other Bindings such as `AddCommand` or `IsBusy`. Can you help me?

Comment: DataType is just a helper to enable Intellisense in the XAML.  It does not have any impact on the runtime behavior of your code

Comment: *"it breaks all the other Bindings"* - create a new Question. In that new question, clarify exactly what you mean by "breaks all the other bindings". If there is a compiler error, give the exact error message. If there is a runtime problem, describe that problem exactly.